# Unknown User(s): --worker --master-host

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, locust

I've moved a Locust Docker implementation into AWS ECS and when ECS tries to provision a task with "--worker --master-host" argument the container exits with a log error of "ERROR/locust.main: Unknown User(s): --worker --master-host a7f7a4f584ae42ee869fcb3a51f6999...".

Has anyone ever had this problem?
I've perviously had success standing this service up using AWS cli and docker compose commands.

I'm using AWS ECS orchestration to run a master host with X number of workers. The master host is working fine but the workers aren't.
I'm using terraform and the command I pass is:
"--worker --master-host a7f7a4f584ae42ee869fcb3a51f69998.locust.service.locust.workers --master-port 5557"

I've tested the host DNS and its valid and working.

The error log returned is:
[2022-02-15 12:50:44,540] 286d5776e86d/ERROR/locust.main: Unknown User(s): --worker --master-host a7f7a4f584ae42ee869fcb3a51f69998.locust.service.locust.workers --master-port 5557

I've been struggling for a couple of days with this now

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the arguments are passed or grouped incorrectly. Locust accepts a last parameter that specifies which User classes to run, and your scripts must have somehow specified ”`--worker --master-host a7f7a4f584ae42ee869fcb3a51f69998.locust.service.locust.workers --master-port 5557`” (as a single parameter)

At least that is my interpretation.

Comment: Hi thanks. I found the problem which was infact an issue with how I was passing the arguments to ECS. 
ECS needs each argument comma separated so it can pass it to the container correctly.
So I used the following which worked out correct:
["--worker", "--master-host", "a7f7a4f584ae42ee869fcb3a51f69998.locust.service.locust.workers", "--master-port", "5557"]